# Feature request to help new users

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

I had this thought the other day on what was concerning new users the most, and one thing I noticed was how new users' questions were regularly downvoted. Being a new user means being exposed to many rules and strict guidelines from this stackexchange, and many learnt it the hard way such as being question banned. You may argue that they had an option to read the tour site, but many users are desperate and view the tour page as another T&C page which they skim or skip completely over.

My suggestion is to change the scaffolding of how the questions were created itself. For example, our current scaffolding as of January 2022 is just 'Title, Body and Tags'. Many reasons why new users' questions are downvoted is because it is a homework question or they did not provide what their working out was. Therefore, by splitting the body into two new text boxes, which is **'Question'** and **'Your work'**. Those would be seperated by a line or something, which forces them to show their working, which teaches them about what a good question's structure is. Not only does this help them not get showered with downvotes, it also teaches them the proper structure the easy way, and not a harsh comment and then a closed question, which they desperately try to save.

About the homework part, we could add a highlighted line about homework, or copy the do's and dont's from the tour page onto the edit page, which will produce a better and more efficient result than scrolling down a block of rules.

Comment: To me it seems that your suggesting something similar to these previous posts: [Should M.SE consider a Question Wizard Guide?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9640). (Maybe there were also some other discussions on this meta related to question wizard - this was the one I was able to find.) This feature request seems a bit related, too: [Could "Ask Question" dialog be more helpful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8720)

Comment: As far as I know, the Ask Question Wizard is only available on [so] (at the moment). If you want to learn a bit more about it, you can find some info (including a few screenshots) here: [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671) Maybe the other links [in the tag-info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/ask-question-wizard/info) might be useful, too.

Comment: So should I just delete this post? @MartinSleziak

Comment: It is up to you, but I would recommend against deleting. You can see that the two posts I linked are ancient - both of them from 2013. If nothing else, if you this question here, there is a chance that some users who know more about the wizard can provide additional information.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Not every question lends itself to a "your work" section.

Comment: May you please give me any examples?

Comment: If you want to cannonball into a pool, the onus is on you to check that there's enough water, it's deep enough, and there are no people in the way. If you don't, and you end up getting hurt, how is it anyone's fault other than your own?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No one is blamed for having any "fault". But there is no harm to set a better sign telling people there's not enough water yet.

Comment: Contest questions are a reasonable example of questions for which one cannot expect work, for example.

Comment: @Sarvesh  We are not here to solve contest questions for users, if they post only a problem statement.  Context is crucial; not necessarily "one's attempt", but contest questions, *like all questions* requires context, to make it clear thought has been given.

Comment: @amWhy I know : I'm just providing a example of why someone may not be able to fill a "your work" section. Other context should be provided in those situations.

Comment: @banana  Do you know how many such "signs" have been modified and added since 2010?  Seldom, if ever, have askers actually attended to such sign posts.  You seem not to realize that you are like one of the 100 askers asking essentiall the same question over the last decade, to which effort and time, and salaries  are spent, with yet another user six months later complaining in meta that we don't do enough to coddle users who refuse to bother learning the rules of the game.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer  Yes, "showing effort" is not the only, nor best way to show context, depending on the nature of the post.  I agree.

Comment: @amWhy: Well, I do realize there are guidelines here and there. *"Seldom, if ever, have askers actually attended to such signposts."* I think this suggests some problem with the "signposts" themselves. And most I don't find OP is mainly complaining about anything in this meta post. Rather, they ask for possible improvements.

Comment: As @MartinSleziak points out, this post is similar to the Wizard suggestion in the linked post by Amzoti.

Comment: @banana  We do not need cartoons and memes to educate.  If askers refuse to take the time to learn how to "play the game", that does not entail that we need to dumb it down and create an entertaining animated sesame street version.  As a new user, I would have found that entirely insulting.

Comment: I do not see what posts you are referring to, @banana.

Comment: @amWhy: It is in the first link of the [first comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34499/feature-request-to-help-new-users?noredirect=1#comment160344_34499). The Stack Overflow site has implemented a [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live).  Not sure why they don't implement it for other sites.

Comment: How about you ask on [meta.se]?  Aaa, or @banana?

Comment: Also [this linked post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/could-ask-question-dialog-be-more-helpful?noredirect=1&lq=1).